# TabBar at bottom of MAUI application

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I created a new MAUI app in Visual Studio with the default application.  I am trying to add a TabBar at the bottom but it is always appearing at the top (see screenshot).  All the examples I have seen and documentation I have read indicate it should be at the bottom.  What am I doing wrong?  This is on Windows.

Here is the AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="letseat.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:letseat"
    >


    <TabBar Route="Home">
        <Tab Icon="dotnet_bot.png" Title="Main">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="dotnet_bot.png" Title="Profile">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfilePage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="dotnet_bot.png" Title="Test">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfilePage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

And the result
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVZSi.png)

Comment: This may be a problem with the .Net Maui Windows platform itself,  you can consider using a custom tabbar renderer to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong.

It looks like [this has been a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6369) for nearly a year, and, unfortunately, appears to be low priority.

However, it still displays the tabs at the bottom in the Android Emulator (pixel 5 API 33). So as of (4/25/2023), it is still a bug, and not expected to be fixed soon (according to the issue notes from Aug 30, 2022, "it is not going to be worked on for the coming release"

[image: screenshot of android vs windows rendering of tabs]

Answer (score 0):

After .NET 7 update, this bug has been resolved.